# Getting roads shapefiles for specific years

Tags: qgis, copernicus

How can I find shapefiles for specific years?

I am analyzing vectors file from the Corine project (land.Copernicus) over time (I have 5 periods; 1990, 2000, 2006, 2012, 2018) and I would like to add roads for those specific years.
I used to find files on DivaGIS but I can't choose the years.

Do you have a recommendation?

Comment: Did you need road data for all Europe or did you have a specific area of interest ? if the later you should mention it as historical ressource may be available only in some area

Comment: Hej JR, I need for Mecklenburg region in Germany

Comment: Have you tried to get this information from Waze.com for example>

Comment: Do you think they have datas from the 90s?

Comment: I had an idea: using rasters instead of shapefile and changing it to shapefiles, do you think it's a good idea?